# how to scroll to index in deeply hierarchical list in react-virtualized

Tags: react-virtualized

The [List component](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md) of [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) offers a property `scrollToIndex` to enable scrolling to a list item that is currently not visible.

The official [tree example](https://rawgit.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/master/playground/tree.html) builds a hierarchical list with hierarchically stacked ul elements - just as expected.

So if index x is scrolled to, this row contains the entire hierarchy that resides under this specific tree element.

In my case there are very few level one elements. But in level 3 there are up to 600 elements. So it is important to be able to scroll an element of level 3 into view.

The `scrollToIndex` can unfortunately not be used for this as all these 600 elements are contained in the same top level index.

The only way I can imagine this to work is by hierarchically creating entire react-virtualized List components instead of ul elements. Then in order to scroll an element into view `scrollToIndex` would be called from top down on every hierarchical level.

Somehow I feel there must be an easier / more feasible way to do this.

Any ideas?

---

update: I had this idea:

- build a function that counts the number of rows above the active node in the hierarchical tree
- multiply that with the row height
- apply this to `scrolltop`in the `List`component

Only problem is: scrolltop is not applied :-(

[This](https://github.com/barbalex/apf/blob/master/app/components/Projekte/StrukturbaumContainer/Strukturbaum/index.js) is the component I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct here. You can't use the `scrollToIndex` to scroll within a large row in the way you're describing. However you could use the `scrollTop` property instead. (Internally `Grid` is just converting the index to a scroll offset anyway.)

```
function render ({ scrollToIndex, ...rest }) {
  // Convert scrollToIndex to scrollStop
  const scrollTop =
    rowOffset + // Position of row within List
    innerOffset // Position of inner target within row

  return (
    <List
      scrollTop={scrollTop}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}
```

PS: This is a pretty cool tree component built on top of react-virtualized. Thought you may find it interesting: https://fritz-c.github.io/react-sortable-tree/

Comment: Wow, saw your answer after updating my question. Thanks. Do you know what I could be doing wrong when applying scrolltop?

Comment: Got it. it is `scrollTop`, not `scrolltop`... Thanks A LOT!

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly as expected when it should be scrolled to a index when loaded.
But with this implementation, when I scroll, it is scrolling back again to scrollTop given number.

Comment: I am doing "scrollTop={index * rowHeight}

Comment: Sorry for bringing up a long ago question. :-)